# ScrollView scrolling speed

Tags: uiscrollview, scroll, performance, scrollview

In my app, I have 2 `ScrollView` s in view.first scroll is placed bottom and then second Scroll placed. if i scroll either first or second both will scroll depends on finger movements. this is working.

But my question is, what if I want the scrolling speed to be different for first scroll and second scroll eg. if the first scroll moves 2px speed then second scroll has to move double the speed of first scroll i.e 4px.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you don't need to work on speed, but on the contentOffset property of the scrollView.
You could have a method that sets the contentOffset of other scrollViews based on a sender scrollView.